# Using an associated type from a Trait as a type constraint?

Tags: generics, rust, traits

Suppose I have this trait, to be implemented by users:

```
pub trait AssetHandler {
    type AssetTraitObjectType;
    fn load_asset(&mut self) -> Option<Box<dyn Any>>;
}
```

I want to provide a utility method on another object which requires `AssetTraitObjectType` to be a trait:

```
pub trait TypedAssetLoader<Handler: AssetHandler> {
    fn load_typed_asset<T>(&self) -> Box<T>
    where
        T: Handler::AssetTraitObjectType; // < cannot refer to the other trait's type like this.
                                          //   compiler doesn't know it's a trait
}
```

In plain language, I want to enforce that `T` on that method always implements the trait provided by `AssetHandler::AssetTraitObjectType`.

Is there any way to make this work?

Comment: Please edit your question to provide a minimal reproducible example containing all of the code necessary to reproduce the error. Also, include the specific error(s) you see in your question.

Comment: @PitaJ updated question to remove external dependencies. There's not really an "error" of the regular kind here, more "the type system has no idea what I mean because my intention isn't valid"

Answer (score 0):

`Handler::AssetTraitObjectType` is not a trait, so it can't be used as a bound. And `load_typed_asset` doesn't need to be generic, you just need to put `Handler::AssetTraitObjectType` in the return type:

```rust
pub trait TypedAssetLoader<Handler: AssetHandler> {
    fn load_typed_asset(&self) -> Box<Handler::AssetTraitObjectType>;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, my goal is that `Handler::AssetTraitObjectType` *should* be a trait, and the `T` should be a concrete type which _implements_ that trait. I assume there's no way to do this, though.

Comment: This concept is called "higher-kinded types". Rust does not have HKTs, but it does have generic associated types, which may be capable of what you're trying to accomplish. We'll need to know more about the context of what your end goal is here.